# Use function from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, methods, webpack, vue.js

Hi everyone I work on webpack and VueJS and I want to use a function in multiple different scripts but I don't want to write the script of these function many times.
So I have 2 files where I want to use my function like this :

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            metadata: null,
        }
    },
    methods:{

    },
    mounted(){
             this.metadata = this.httpGet("myurl");


    }
}
```

And like this :

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            metadata: null,
        }
    },
    methods:{

    },
    mounted(){
             this.metadata = this.httpGet("myurl");


    }
}
```

And this is the third part where i want to create my function :

```
httpGet(theUrl){
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // true for asynchronous request
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);

}
```

I don't found the exact code to make it works. So please tell me how I can use imports, require or things like this. I don't want to use vuex because it is to complex for the little thing I want to do. 
The final objective is to get a script where I can store different functions and use them in multiples others scripts.

Comment: Sounds like you just need webpack to be able to resolve your imports and exports.

Comment: check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: I use webpack soo how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

For this you can just use a [`mixin`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html):

**MetaData.js**

```
const MetaData = {
    data(){
        return {
            metadata: null,
        }
    },
    methods:{
       httpGet(theUrl){
         var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // true for asynchronous request
         xmlHttp.send(null);
         return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);

      }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.metadata = this.httpGet("myurl");
    }
}

export default MetaData
```

Now in your component you can use it like so:

```
<template>
  <div>{{metadata}}</div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import MetaData from './mixins/MetaData' // wherever you have saved the mixin 

  export default{
    mixins: [MetaData]
  }
</script>
```

That will automatically merge the two objects together, so you can use all the instance properties in your mixin in your Vue component you imported it in to.

Here's a JSFiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/c5takojL/

Comment: I'm not sure it works in the web pack environement. It says : ncaught ReferenceError: Metadata is not defined. It is like if const Metadata in my js file didn't worked.

Comment: Make sure you have [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) being applied to your .js files files in your webpack config.